# Laravel whereBetween query working incorrectly

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I have $startDate and $endDate

```
$startDate = Carbon\Carbon::create(2015, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0);
$endDate = Carbon\Carbon::create(2016, 1, 25, 23, 59, 59);
```

and I have this query

```
App\InspectionForm::whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])->select('created_at')->get();
```

At first, it looks like its output is correct

[Output part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNVU5.png)

scrolling up...

[Output part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOtvo.png)

it seems there's something wrong with the date comparison.
Or is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a variable called `$endingDate` but the variable you pass into whereBetween is called `$endDate`.

Comment: oh sorry about that, i didn't see. i'll edit that. but yeah, i'm using the right variables. i just didn't notice posting the wrong ones. thanks for noticing. :)

Comment: WOW!!! actually you were right!!! How stupid of me! Thanks for noticing. You were a life saver. Thanks!!! I'm so stupid.